# Session based login doesn't work on remote server

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm currently building a php based login for a website which happens to work in my localhost created with Wamp, but it does not work if I copy my files over to a remote server and set up the same database there. The connection with the database should be okay, because I can register a new user on the site and the site also shows everything that is to be taken off from the database.

The problem with the login part of the site is that it just simply doesn't do anything at all. I try to login, and if it's with the proper account details, it says login is succesful and it also echoes the session variables for testing purposes (for example: it shows the given user's ID that is saved in the database). But when I navigate to an other page, the user is just not logged in at all. I'll try to list all the code here that should be important to see what's the problem:

The login form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="loginForm">
    <fieldset>
        <table id="form_Table">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="login_Username">Username</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="login_Username" id="login_Username" class="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="login_Password">Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="login_Password" id="login_Password" class="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="login_Submit" value="Log in" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The php code which handles the login procedure in the submit.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['login_Submit'])) { 
    if (!empty($_POST['login_Username']) && !empty($_POST['login_Password'])) {

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_Username']);
        $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_Password']));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
        $checklogin = mysql_query($sql);


        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result === FALSE) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == "1") {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
            $group = $row['group'];
            $userid = $row['id'];
            $cart = array();
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['Group'] = $group;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $userid;
            $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; 
            echo '<h1>Logged in successfully!</h1>';
            //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;index.php">';
            echo $_SESSION['Username'];
            echo $_SESSION['LoggedIn'];
            echo $_SESSION['UserID'];
            echo $_SESSION['Group'];
            } else {
            echo '<h1>Wrong username or password!</h1>';
                }
            }
        }
```

index.php:

```
<?php
@session_start();
include 'header.php';
?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
@session_start();

//connect variables are here

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL connection error: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL database error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

?>
```

header.php:

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; 
@session_start();?>
```

My best guess was that for some reason the site does not keep the session variables after I leave the given page, that's why I added the @session_start() to multiple pages, but it does not work this way either.

As I have ran out of ideas of what could I do now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any redirects from `www` to `non-www` pages? As setting a session on one will not be set on the other.

Comment: You should look into MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements, mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: is session_start on all pages including the submit where you set the inital $_SESSION variables? Try removing @, before session_start. do you get any errors?

Comment: @Fredd Yes, I do got errors, the @ was the solution for them. If I remove the @ character I get the following two errors:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent  and Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent. As far as I know it should be caused when the session_start() isn't on the very beginning of the files, but I made sure several times they are there (I edited the header.php just now for this), but I could never get rid of the issue.

Comment: Not entirely sure but if you are including a page with session_start already, then you don't need to add it again. so try removing it from header if every page already includes connection.php. make sure nothing is printing to the screen etc before each one.

Comment: I left only one session_start(), happens the same thing. Either a warning, or nothing happens if I put the @ before the session start. One thing I noticed is that if I put that @ there and there's no warning, in the source code there's a blank line above the html doctype and there's also a blank ~20px tall blank space above my site. What really bugs me is that it just works on localhost without any problem. I think I'll contact the server provider, see if they have anything to add.

Comment: @LaszloParazs You should not suppress warnings with the @ symbol simply to make them go away. Those warnings are there for a reason. You're probably not seeing the same thing on localhost because you have error reporting turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a "headers already sent" error, it should specify the file and line responsible for the premature output.

I suspect you might have a trailing whitespace after a PHP closing tag in one of your files. Because this is such a problem, it's a good idea to completely omit the closing PHP tag. The PHP parser doesn't care, so why should you? :)

A simple fix might be to simply use output buffering, but it shouldn't be necessary in this instance.

Have you checked to see if a cookie is being set? Are you calling `session_destroy()` anywhere? `session_start()` should only ever be called once. It would probably make sense to shove it into a bootstrap file, and include that from each of your pages.

Comment: That error specifies the same line I have the session_start() in, line 1.
I double checked for possible white spaces, I couldn't find any, and I shrunk the code as much as I could.

Comment: Is there any chance you could paste (perhaps on pastie.org) the source code for the page this is happening on, after it's been sent to the browser, and post the link to it? Usually pressing CTRL+U from within your browser will display the source code for the page.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I wasn't at home. There you go: http://pastie.org/8498057 However, I decided the best I can do now is to rebuild the site with mysqli/PDO step by step and see if it's going to work out or not.

Comment: Looking at your source code, it looks like there is a "<br />" being output before the cookie is sent. I suspect that's the problem and if you find where that's being output, you'll fix the problem.  I suggest looking into output buffering. It will ensure that you don't output anything to the browser until you flush the buffer (which you'd normally do right at the end of your app logic). It's rediculously easy to implement (2 lines of code). The downside is that if you exit from your app, (I don't see why you should need to) nothing will be output, but it should save a rewrite.

Comment: Well I rebuilt the site and it works well now. Whilst gazing through the code I couldn't find what caused my error, or where was that whitespace (if any) or something else. The rewrite wasn't a big deal, at least my code is better formatted now. Thanks for the help.